# "Can't Connect to Server" from 2nd virtual host on VPS

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, vps, debian-wheezy, mod-ssl

I'm using Debian 7 Wheezy and Apache 2.2.22, and I'm setting up Virtual Hosts for a number of websites on my VPS. I've successfully configured the VirtualHost directives for one of the sites, but the second one continually gives "Problem Loading Page" in Firefox. I've run `configtest` and it has verified all my syntax is correct, and I've checked all the permissions. Everything on the 2nd domain is pretty much copy/pasted from the first, so I'm not sure what the issue is, as there are no entries into `/var/log/apache2/error.log` other than where I have reloaded the configurations:

```
/# cat /var/log/apache2/error.log
[Thu May 29 01:19:00 2014] [notice] Graceful restart requested, doing restart
[Thu May 29 01:19:00 2014] [info] Init: Seeding PRNG with 656 bytes of entropy
[Thu May 29 01:19:00 2014] [info] Init: Generating temporary RSA private keys (512/1024 bits)
[Thu May 29 01:19:00 2014] [info] Init: Generating temporary DH parameters (512/1024 bits)
[Thu May 29 01:19:00 2014] [debug] ssl_scache_shmcb.c(253): shmcb_init allocated 512000 bytes of shared memory
[Thu May 29 01:19:00 2014] [debug] ssl_scache_shmcb.c(272): for 511920 bytes (512000 including header), recommending 32 subcaches, 133 indexes each
[Thu May 29 01:19:00 2014] [debug] ssl_scache_shmcb.c(306): shmcb_init_memory choices follow
[Thu May 29 01:19:00 2014] [debug] ssl_scache_shmcb.c(308): subcache_num = 32
[Thu May 29 01:19:00 2014] [debug] ssl_scache_shmcb.c(310): subcache_size = 15992
[Thu May 29 01:19:00 2014] [debug] ssl_scache_shmcb.c(312): subcache_data_offset = 3208
[Thu May 29 01:19:00 2014] [debug] ssl_scache_shmcb.c(314): subcache_data_size = 12784
[Thu May 29 01:19:00 2014] [debug] ssl_scache_shmcb.c(316): index_num = 133
[Thu May 29 01:19:00 2014] [info] Shared memory session cache initialised
[Thu May 29 01:19:00 2014] [info] Init: Initializing (virtual) servers for SSL
[Thu May 29 01:19:00 2014] [info] mod_ssl/2.2.22 compiled against Server: Apache/2.2.22, Library: OpenSSL/1.0.1e
[Thu May 29 01:19:00 2014] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Debian) PHP/5.4.4-14+deb7u9 mod_ssl/2.2.22 OpenSSL/1.0.1e mod_perl/2.0.7 Perl/v5.14.2 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu May 29 01:19:00 2014] [info] Server built: Mar  4 2013 22:05:16
[Thu May 29 01:19:00 2014] [debug] prefork.c(1023): AcceptMutex: sysvsem (default: sysvsem)
```

I've ensured to enable each vhost with `a2ensite {sitename.conf}` with no errors there, either.

Below are the contents of the configuration files...

/etc/apache2/apache2.conf

```
# Global configuration
#
LockFile ${APACHE_LOCK_DIR}/accept.lock
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}

Timeout 300
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 5

##
## Server-Pool Size Regulation (MPM specific)
##

# prefork MPM
# StartServers: number of server processes to start
# MinSpareServers: minimum number of server processes which are kept spare
# MaxSpareServers: maximum number of server processes which are kept spare
# MaxClients: maximum number of server processes allowed to start
# MaxRequestsPerChild: maximum number of requests a server process serves
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    StartServers          5
    MinSpareServers       5
    MaxSpareServers      10
    MaxClients          150
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>

# worker MPM
# StartServers: initial number of server processes to start
# MinSpareThreads: minimum number of worker threads which are kept spare
# MaxSpareThreads: maximum number of worker threads which are kept spare
# ThreadLimit: ThreadsPerChild can be changed to this maximum value during a
#              graceful restart. ThreadLimit can only be changed by stopping
#              and starting Apache.
# ThreadsPerChild: constant number of worker threads in each server process
# MaxClients: maximum number of simultaneous client connections
# MaxRequestsPerChild: maximum number of requests a server process serves
<IfModule mpm_worker_module>
    StartServers          2
    MinSpareThreads      25
    MaxSpareThreads      75
    ThreadLimit          64
    ThreadsPerChild      25
    MaxClients          150
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>

# event MPM
# StartServers: initial number of server processes to start
# MinSpareThreads: minimum number of worker threads which are kept spare
# MaxSpareThreads: maximum number of worker threads which are kept spare
# ThreadsPerChild: constant number of worker threads in each server process
# MaxClients: maximum number of simultaneous client connections
# MaxRequestsPerChild: maximum number of requests a server process serves
<IfModule mpm_event_module>
    StartServers          2
    MinSpareThreads      25
    MaxSpareThreads      75
    ThreadLimit          64
    ThreadsPerChild      25
    MaxClients          150
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>

# These need to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}

#
# AccessFileName: The name of the file to look for in each directory
# for additional configuration directives.  See also the AllowOverride
# directive.
#
AccessFileName .htaccess

#
# The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being
# viewed by Web clients.
#
<Files ~ "^\.ht">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Satisfy all
</Files>


DefaultType None

HostnameLookups Off

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
LogLevel debug

# Include module configuration:
Include mods-enabled/*.load
Include mods-enabled/*.conf

# Include list of ports to listen on and which to use for name based vhosts
Include ports.conf

#
# The following directives define some format nicknames for use with
# a CustomLog directive (see below).
# If you are behind a reverse proxy, you might want to change %h into %{X-Forwarded-For}i
#
#
LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

<Directory "/var/www">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
</Directory>

# Include generic snippets of statements
Include conf.d/

# Include the virtual host configurations:
Include sites-enabled/*.conf
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

/etc/apache2/sites-available/site1.net.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName site1.net
    ServerAlias site1.net *.site1.net
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/site1"
    ErrorLog "/var/www/site1/logs/error.log"
    CustomLog "/var/www/site1/logs/access.log" vhost_combined
    <Directory "/var/www/site1">
        Options None
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Satisfy Any
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

/etc/apache2/sites-available/site2.com.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName site2.com
    ServerAlias site2.com *.site2.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/site2"
    ErrorLog "/var/www/site2/logs/error.log"
    CustomLog "/var/www/site2/logs/access.log" vhost_combined
    <Directory "/var/www/site2">
        Options None
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Satisfy Any
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I've also tried setting NameVirtualHost like:

```
Listen 80
NameVirtualHost 23.88.121.82:80
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80
```

and the VirtualHost Directives:

```
<VirtualHost 23.88.121.82:80>
...
</VirtualHost>
```

for both sites, but that causes the first site to fail, as well.

I'm wondering if I need to set up individual IPs for each site, possibly? I have 2 more IPv4 and 3 IPv6 addresses available, if that would make a difference.
Also, in the grand scheme of things, I will need to enable SSL for the first site. I've been reading that I'll need to basically just mimic the directives for listening on port 80, only on port 443, and make sure mod_ssl is enabled?

**EDIT**: I just ran `apache2 -t` to test the config files that way, and got the error: `apache2: bad user name ${APACHE_RUN_USER}`. However, `apachectl configtest` returns `Syntax OK`. There are no other mentions of errors with the mutex anywhere else, however. I was pretty sure if there was an error with the user apache was supposed to run under, the server wouldn't start at all...

**EDIT 2**: Restarting apache fixed the bad user name error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that there was an issue with the DNS settings, and all the Apache config is correct. :/